# Структура для next.js приложения

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nextjs, next.js

Подскажите как правильно реализовать структуру приложения.
Есть три компонента: сервер(експрес), клиент(next.js), админка.
Сервер где то себе лежит, ходит в базу и по апи отдает данные.
Клиент в папке клиент, там внутри next всё ок. Как быть с админкой? Создавать к ней доступ через роутинг некста и там внутри всю логику писать? Или лучше делать на отдельном порту и там чистый реакт, например? Насколько я понимаю, если я сделаю админку внутри некста то она будет в клиенстком бандле? Как вообще делают такие вещи?